# TextInpuLayout hint color when not focused

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I'm building a custom TextInputLayout where the hint turns red when the error is set.
It works however only when the TextInputLayout has focus. After another field gains focus it turns grey again.
Here's my style:

```
<style name="ErrorMessage" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas which attribute I have to add so that the hint stays red even after focus is lost?

EDIT:
Here's the code I've tried (Including the proposed solution in Bishoy Abd's comment):
The `MainActivity`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomTextInput textInputLayout1;
    CustomTextInput textInputLayout2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View textInput1Root = findViewById(R.id.text_input_1);
        View textInput2Root = findViewById(R.id.text_input_2);

        TextInputLayout textInput1 = textInput1Root.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextInputLayout textInput2 = textInput2Root.findViewById(R.id.label);

        textInput1.setHint("Edit Text 1");
        textInput2.setHint("Edit Text 2");

        textInputLayout1 = new CustomTextInput(this, textInput1Root);
        textInputLayout2 = new CustomTextInput(this, textInput2Root);

        AppCompatButton validateButton = findViewById(R.id.validate_button);
        validateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateFields();
            }
        });

        textInput1Root.findViewById(R.id.edit_text).setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    validate(((EditText) v).getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        textInput2Root.findViewById(R.id.edit_text).setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    validate(((EditText) v).getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate(String txt) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(txt)) {
            textInputLayout1.hideErrorMessage();
        } else {
            textInputLayout1.setErrorMessage("Invalid");
            textInputLayout1.showErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    private void validateFields() {
        if (!isFieldValid(findViewById(R.id.text_input_1))) {
            textInputLayout1.setErrorMessage("Invalid");
            textInputLayout1.showErrorMessage();
        } else {
            textInputLayout1.hideErrorMessage();
        }
        if (!isFieldValid(findViewById(R.id.text_input_2))) {
            textInputLayout2.setErrorMessage("Invalid");
            textInputLayout2.showErrorMessage();
        } else {
            textInputLayout1.hideErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    private boolean isFieldValid(View inputField) {
        TextInputLayout input = inputField.findViewById(R.id.label);
        EditText editText = inputField.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        if (editText.getText() == null || editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `CustomTextInput`:

```
  public class CustomTextInput extends LinearLayout {

    private String errorMessage;
    private final String defaultErrorMessage = "ERROR_MESSAGE_NOT_SET";
    //Children:
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
    private AppCompatEditText appComaptEditText;


    public CustomTextInput(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInput(Context context, View rootView) {
        this(context);
        errorMessage = defaultErrorMessage;
        if (rootView != null) {
            textInputLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            appComaptEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        }
    }

    public CustomTextInput(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void showErrorMessage() {
        textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.ErrorMessage);
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
        textInputLayout.setError(errorMessage);
    }

    public EditText getEditText() {
        return appComaptEditText;
    }

    public TextInputLayout getLabel() {
        return textInputLayout;
    }

    public void hideErrorMessage() {
        textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.Hint);
        textInputLayout.setError(null);
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String message) {
        errorMessage = message;
    }

    public void setHint(String hint) {
        textInputLayout.setHint(hint);
    }
}
```

The `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0011</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>

The `styles.xml`:

    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Hint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ErrorMessage" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The `custom_text_input.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test.textinputlayouterrortest.CustomTextInput
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_text_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorMessage"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Hint">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</test.textinputlayouterrortest.CustomTextInput>
```

And the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="test.textinputlayouterrortest.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/text_input_1"
        layout="@layout/custom_text_input"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/text_input_2"
        layout="@layout/custom_text_input"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/validate_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="validate"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your code!!

Comment: @HemantParmar shared :)

Comment: I found out that the hints color when not focused is defined by the textColorHint set in the app theme. Does anybody know how I could change it programmatically, or have 2 values for it for the failed and correct state?

Answer (score 1):

XML (abc.xml) selector to set the color of label in different states

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/select_your_color" app:state_empty_text="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/select_your_color"/> <!-- default color -->
</selector>
```

now define edittext style in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="EditTextLayout">

    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/abc</item>
</style>
```

now apply this style to your edittext and change the color according.

Comment: As far as I know, I can't place a selector in the colors.xml. Did you mean @drawable/abc instead of @color/abc? I also get the error: attribute state_empty_text not found.

Comment: remove this line `ttribute state_empty_text` & we can place color in selector.

Comment: If I remove the line, the error disappears, but the hint turns still grey when the TextInputLayout looses focus.

Comment: did you add `style="@style/EditTextLayout"` in your editext?

Comment: Yes, I added the style attribute to the AppComatEditText in the TextInputLayout.

Answer (score -1):

suppose you are using two EdtitText passwordEt,userNameEt inside your `TextInputLayout`s

```
passwordEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    validatePassword(((EditText) v).getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

userNameEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    validateUserName(((EditText) v).getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

 private void validatePassword(String pass) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
    }
    else{
        textInputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.password_error));
    }
}
```

the same goes for `userNameEt` and other `EditText`s

Comment: This did not solve my problem. I'll post the code I've tried shortly.